# js script to detect debug version of flash player IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, version, flash, detect

With [swfobject.js](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) I can get the version of the installed flash player, I can get release and build numbers, but I don't know if it is the debug or standard version. I could find out with AS3 (flash.system.Capabilities.isDebugger) but I need it in JavaScript.

My problem is when there is a flash player debug installed on IE, there is a 6 seconds delay before the swf is displayed. I want to detect with javascript (before the swf is started) if the user has debug FlashPlayer to warn him that he will have to wait.